# monkeyrunner Running getChildren() on view will cause "Node with given ID does not exist exception"

Tags: android-testing, monkeyrunner

I have nav drawer with "Settings" as TextView without an ID.
I can get the home_nav_view but when trying to iterate over the children I get the exception "com.android.chimpchat.core.ChimpException: Node with given ID does not exist"

Am I doing something wrong?

```
>>> c = easy_device.getViewById("com.catonetworks.vpnclient:id/home_nav_view")
>>> print c.getLocation().right
840
>>> print c.getLocation().bottom
1794
>>> print dir(c)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__str__', 'getAccessibilityIds', 'getChecked', 'getChildren', 'getEnabled', 'getFocused', 'getLocation', 'getParent', 'getSelected', 'getText', 'getViewClass', 'setFocused', 'setSelected']
>>> print c.getChildren()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    at com.android.chimpchat.ChimpManager.queryView(ChimpManager.java:415)
    at com.android.chimpchat.core.ChimpView.queryView(ChimpView.java:54)
    at com.android.chimpchat.core.ChimpView.getChildren(ChimpView.java:175)
    at com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyView.getChildren(MonkeyView.java:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

com.android.chimpchat.core.ChimpException: com.android.chimpchat.core.ChimpException: Node with given ID does not exist
```

Comment: I found out the problem is that under the view there are Preferences and Android converts them to TextView that is why they don't have ID

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that under the view there are Preferences and Android converts them to TextView that is why they don't have ID